# Why isn't there an "I" (Incredibles logo) on Jack-Jack's suit?

Tags: character, incredibles-2

Why isn't there the Incredibles logo on Jack-Jack's suit in *Incredibles 2* ? Is it because Pixar want to portray Jack-Jack as a possible antagonist in upcoming movies?

The logo contains a homing signal which detects where the person is. So don't they want to know Jack-Jack's location in Incredibles 3 (in case if it gets released in the future)?

Comment: "Is it because of Pixar wanna portray JackJack as possible Antagonist for upcoming movies?" I haven't seen *Incredibles 2* yet, but that's... quite the leap in logic there.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what Pixar's intentions are for future works in the setting, that sort of thing is off-topic.  As for why there's no logo... technically that's on Edna.  She made the suit (to help contain Jack-Jack's powers) without asking Mr Incredible first (he was barely awake anyway.)  Maybe she didn't want to be presumptuous.

Comment: Note that Jack-Jack could be located in the fourth dimension using the handheld screen.  We aren't told exactly how it works, but it's entirely plausible that there *is* some kind of tracking technology in his suit that enables this;  it just isn't embedded in a logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jack Jack's suit has a few notable differences to the rest of his family.

[image]

- Doesn't have the Incredible logo
- Doesn't have the "belt"
- Doesn't have the accented underwear line
- Doesn't have gloves
- Doesn't have boots

**His outfit is essentially baby footie pajamas.**

This is probably because, as a baby, he isn't expected to perform any missions or get into combat (even though Edna designed the suit with all the *basics*, including resistance to bullets and fire).

[image]